# PyCharm will not run def takecommand() it will just say the command I have given to say and will exit with code 0

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, pyaudio

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Hello There')
engine.say('How can I help you?')
engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

This is my code but, def take_command will not run only the assistant will speak some lines and exit with code 0.

Comment: Is this your full code? You never call the function `take_command`.

Comment: `def` **defines** a function. After it is defined you need to **call** it like this **`take_command()`** to execute the code in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt, i.e. add call and error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask